# FreeRADIUS - Delete user from database when session has expired

Tags: php, mysql, database, radius, freeradius

I am using FreeRADIUS along with MySQL to authenticate users.

Users are saved in the **radcheck** table. User attributes are saved in the **radreply** table.

For example I have a user named Bob in the **radcheck** table.

```
username | attribute           | op | value
------------------------------------------------
Bob      | Cleartext-Password  | := | password12
```

Bob has a **Session-Timeout** value of 60 (1 minute) in the **radreply** table.

```
username | attribute       | op | value
------------------------------------------------
Bob      | Session-Timeout | := | 60
Bob      | Idle-Timeout    | := | 60
```

This all works fine. My problem is that RADIUS just re-authenticates Bob straight away. I assume this is because Bob still exists in the **radcheck** table.

Is there a way to remove Bob from the **radcheck** and **radreply** tables after the **Session-Timeout** time has been reached?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom login using Perl/PHP script in **postacctsql** using Perl/PHP module in Freeradius. **postacctsql** will give you the user who is session timeout and then you can write a custom script to delete a record from Mysql DB. You can find many examples of such scrip on google.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct behavior of radius. If bob is auth well, session times out in 60 seconds. Idle timeout is not nessessary if <= session-timeout. You have to count something to a maximum you have set and then change access from accept to reject. Next time session-timeout reached bob can not reauth